# Program will not exit a do-while loop

Tags: c++, calculator, do-while

I'm trying to make a simple calculator in C++. Here is a portion of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int math;
    int a1;
    int a2 = 0;
    int a3 = 1;
    int answer;
    int amount = 0;
    int achecker = 1;

    cout << "Welcome to my calculator! Type '1' to add, type '2' to subtract, "
            "type '3' to multiply, type '4' to divide, and type '5' to exit."
         << endl;
    cin >> math;

    while (math = 1)
    {
        cout << "Input how many numbers you wish to add:" << endl;
        cin >> amount;
        achecker = amount;
        do
        {
            cout << "Input the number you wish to add:" << endl;
            cin >> a1;
            answer = a1 + a2;
            a2 = a1;
            achecker = achecker - achecker + 1;
        } while (achecker < amount);
        cout << answer;
    }
```

The problem I am encountering is that when the program gets into the do-while loop, it never comes out, it just keeps on asking for the user to input a number. I have gone over this several times and I have no idea what the problem is. Can someone help?

Comment: [Turn up your warning level.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbe8856d94bfe1c6)

Comment: This expression `achecker = achecker - achecker + 1;` assigns `1` to `achecker`, regardless of its previous value (hint: `achecker - achecker` is zero; zero plus one is one).

Comment: .. And indent the code

Comment: `while(math=1)` isn't looking very promising. Try `while((cin >> math) && (math != 5))` and lose the `cin >> math` immediately above it.

Comment: you are missing a final `}` too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all , you should be writing **while(math==1)** sicnce **math=1** is an assignment operator not a check operator.

Secondly, instead of **while** , use **if** since you want to do the calculation for addition only once , putting it in **while** loop will make it an infinite loop.

Thirdly , in the **do - while loop** , the condition should be **while(achecker>=0)**, because your condition will always give a true value.So, actually , there is no need of achecker, simply keep decrementing amount by one for each loop run and keep the condition as **while(amount>=0)** .

One, more improvement i would like to suggest , though not required - 
declare **answer** as **int answer = 0;**. For each loop run , accept a new value in a1 and then for adding , write **answer=answer+a1**. This should serve your purpose.

So, edited code according to me should be -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int math;
  int a1;
  int a3 = 1;
  int answer = 0;
  int amount = 0;
  int achecker = 1;

  cout << "Welcome to my calculator! Type '1' to add, type '2' to subtract, type '3' to      multiply, type '4' to divide, and type '5' to exit." << endl;
  cin >> math;

  if(math == 1){
  cout << "Input how many numbers you wish to add:" << endl;
  cin >> amount;
  do{
  cout << "Input the number you wish to add:" << endl;
  cin >> a1;
  answer = answer + a1;
  amount = amount - 1;
  }while(amount>=0);
  cout << answer;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong condition check in the while loop.

`match=1` is assignment operation and not equality check, which is what you are trying to do. The assignment will always return 1(true) so you have an infinite loop.

replace `match=1` with `match==1` for your code to work

Comment: Thanks, but it still keeps on looping through the do loop.

Comment: print amount values for doing debugging. it will help

Answer (score 1):

`achecker = achecker - achecker + 1;` is always equal to 1. So I think you have an error in that line.